# Maven ships dependencies inside war but not in jar

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jar, dependencies, war

I have two maven projects, one (I will call it core) is an ejb-jar (ejb) and the other a war (client).

My client project consumes some ejbs inside my core...so far so good.

But I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException inside my core application because it can't find one class from apache-beanutils...I have set this dependency with compile scope in it's pom.xml but it does not get shipped inside the output jar.

When I check my client.war package I see every compile-scoped dependency inside the WEB-INF/lib folder...but in my core.jar I don't see any of it's dependencies...I'm totally confused about this.

Can someone help me? I tried to google it before asking but I didn't find anything useful so far..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven assembly plugin to bundle all the jars in one super jar.

See this: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)